# Construction of Ito Integral: Doubt from Oksendal, Chapter $3$, Page-$27$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In the book **"Stochastic Differential Equations"** by Oksendal, at the page $27$, in the last few lines he has written

> Define $g_{n}(t,\omega) := \int_{0}^{t}\psi_{n}(s-t)h(s,\omega)ds$. Then, $g_{n}(.,\omega)$ is continuous for each $\omega $ & $|g_{n}(t,\omega)| \leq M$ . Since $h \in \nu$ , we can show that: $g_{n}(t,.)$ is $\mathcal F_{t}$-measurable $\forall t$.

-where: $h \in \nu$ such that: $|h(t,\omega)| \leq M ; \forall (t,\omega)$ & for each $n$, let $\psi_{n}$ be a non-negative, continuous function on $\mathbb R$ such that:

i) $\psi_{n}(x) = 0 $ for $x \leq -\frac{1}{n}$ & $x \geq 0$

ii) $\int_{\mathbb R} \psi_{n}(x) dx = 1$.

Can someone please explain to me: How $g_{n}(t,.)$ is $\mathcal F_{t}$-measurable $\forall t$??

P.S. :- As referred by the author, I have checked Karatzas & Shreeve. The setup there is bit more complicated & I couldn't find out from there.

Any detailed explanation is welcome!! Thank You!!

Comment: What is $\nu$....?

Comment: $\nu = \nu(S,T)$ be the class of functions $f(t,\omega):[0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb R $ such that

i) $(t,\omega) \to f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathbb B \times \mathbb F$-measurable, where $\mathbb B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0, \infty)$.


ii) $f(t, \omega)$ is $\mathbb F_{t}$-adapted.

iii)$E[\int_{S}^{T}f(t, \omega)^{2}dt] \lt \infty$